# Line and circle intersection points

Tags: c++, geometry

I have a circle with center at (0, 0) and a line given by the equation y = kx. I need to derive a formula to find the intersection points of this line with a circle. I know the equation shown [at the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POLHu.png), but I have a problem with converting the equation of a line from the form y = kx to the form Ax + By + C = 0

Comment: this is about maths, not about code or c++

Comment: There are plenty of "line circle intersection" questions in this site. Please, look for them.

Comment: `y=kx` is the same as `kx-y=0`. So `A=k`, `B=-1` and `C=0`

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I need to find a solution in C-lang. So this question is about code too. But it is based on mathematics, of course.

Comment: you need to do the maths first. Before you don't know the formula you don't need to start writing code.

Comment: @Moongod: no, the site is to discuss specific programming questions when you already have the code. Your question is clearly maths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For circle radius `R` centered at `(0,0)` we can easily find two intersections with line of form `y=kx`:

```
fi = atan(k)
x1 = R * cos(fi)
y1 = R * sin(fi)
x2 = - R * cos(fi)
y2 = - R * sin(fi)
```

Or in terms of `k` without trig. functions:

```
coeff = R / sqrt(1 + k^2)
x1 = coeff * k
y1 = coeff
x2 = - coeff * k
y2 = - coeff
```

The first approach refers to the rule that `k` coefficient in `y = kx+b` corresponds to tangent of angle between line and OX axis.

The second way - solution of system for line and circle equations

```
y = kx
y^2 + x^2 = R^2`
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works great. Could you tell by what geometric rules this formula was derived? Or where can I read about it?

Comment: Added to answer.

Answer (score 0):

The conversion is straightforward.

```
y = k.x <-> -k.x + 1.y + 0 = 0
```